# How to count rows within a given date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I've tried to use this code to count rows & also to group the dates by count over the last 2 days but its not working either

```
select EventDateTime, count(EventDateTime)
from [dbo].[AttributionFact]
where EventDateTime >= '2022-12-29' and
     EventDateTime < '2021-12-28'
group by EventDateTime
order by EventDateTime;
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Those backslashes in your query aren't valid syntax.

Comment: Yes, I think it must be a posting error on my part: select 

EventDateTime, count(EventDateTime)
from [dbo].[AttributionFact]
where EventDateTime >= '2022-12-29' and
     EventDateTime < '2021-12-28'
group by EventDateTime
order by EventDateTime;

Comment: You are looking for a date that's greater than or equal to Dec, 29 and simultaneously less than Dec, 28 of the previous year...

Comment: I see that @gimix thank you for that, is there a way to group the count by 28th and 29th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you provided:

You have used the wrong operator for comparison in the WHERE clause. The >= and < operators are for comparing values that are greater than or less than, respectively. In this case, you want to use the BETWEEN operator to specify a range of values.

The dates in the WHERE clause are also incorrect. You are trying to get rows with a EventDateTime between '2022-12-29' and '2021-12-28', but these dates are in the wrong order. The BETWEEN operator requires the lower bound to come before the upper bound.

In the SELECT clause, you are using count(EventDateTime) to count the number of rows. However, this will always return the total number of rows in the table, because COUNT counts all non-NULL values. If you want to count the number of rows for each distinct value of EventDateTime, you should use COUNT(*) instead.

Here's how the corrected query should look:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,EventDateTime), COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AttributionFact]
WHERE EventDateTime BETWEEN '2021-12-28' AND '2022-12-29'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,EventDateTime)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,EventDateTime);
```

This will select the EventDateTime column and the count of rows for each distinct value of EventDateTime, and return the results sorted by EventDateTime.

Comment: Yes this works but I am getting a long list for 28th and 29th, is there a way to just get the sum and the 2 dates ? e.g. 

2021-12-28 1000
2021-12-29 1500

Comment: try using `CONVERT(DATE,[...])`

Comment: Have a read of [What do `BETWEEN` and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0):

If `EventDateTime` has a time component then the `>= AND <` syntax **is correct, contrary to the answer which suggests `BETWEEN`.**

A read of [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) will explain why: `BETWEEN` is the equivalent of `>= AND <=`, which is not usually the intention. Instead, for `datetime` and other fractional values, you need `>= AND <`.

You just need to swap the values around, and also increase the end date to *after* the end of the second day.

It also seems that you want to group by date, so you need a `GROUP BY CONVERT(date,...`

```sql
select
  CONVERT(date, af.EventDateTime) AS EventDate,
  count(*)
from dbo.AttributionFact af
where af.EventDateTime >= '2022-12-28'
  and af.EventDateTime <  '2021-12-30'
group by
  CONVERT(date, af.EventDateTime)
order by
  EventDate;
```